# Sympy code generation for complicated expressions - interim variables?

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to figure out how to generate C code for complicated expressions in sympy. The examples I could find by googleing are trivial, i.e., generate code for f[i] = x[i]*y[i].

What I'd like to do is generate things for more complicated expressions, for example

```
f[i] = x[i] y[x[i]]
```

where y can be a more complicated function of x, for instance

```
y(x) = y_0 + y_1*z(x) + y_2*z(x)^2
z(x) = z_0 + z_1*x + z_2*x^2
```

Comment: cse and ccode are two functions that can help with that. I would start by looking at what they can do.

Comment: cse seems to detect and collect common subexpressions. Here the problem is the reverse: I know what the common subexpressions are, but I don't know how to feed them in to ccode.

Comment: Could you post an example of generating code for the trivial example that works for you?